# jquery - how to select the id and last element of the longest out of four arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-mobile

I have four DIV elements on my page. Each has it's own array which I attached using data().

Depending on user interaction (on page navigation) jquery stores loaded element IDs in one of the arrays.

The setup and pushing elements works and looks like this:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="panel")').each(function(index) {
    if ( $(this).jqmData('hash') == 'history' ) {
         var id = $(this).jqmData('id');
         $(this).data("stack", []);
         // inital entry = startpage
         $(this).data("stack").push('#'+$(this).find('.starter').attr('id')); 
         }
});
```

Adding elements:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').bind( "pagechange", function( event) {
      var $targetPanel = $( event.target ),                 
      $targetPage = '#'+ $.mobile.path.stripHash( hash );   
      $targetPanel.data("stack").push($targetPage);
      });
```

I now need to know which array is the longest and what the last entry was?

No clue how to do that...

Can't use maxValue or math, as I only have entries like #pageSome, #pageOther. There must be a better way than looping through all arrays, getting their length and trying to if-else highest value...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sort method to find the longest array

```
var arr = [];
arr.push([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
arr.push([1,2,3,4,5,7,8]);
arr.push([1,2,3,4,5]);
arr.sort(function(a,b){return b.length - a.length});
// arr is now sorted with [0]  being the longest array
```

Then in order to get those arrays to be sorted, you could get them with a function like so:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="panel"),div:jqmData(role="page")').each(function(index) {
    arr.push($(this).data("stack"));
});
```

or if the data in the arrays don't change often, you could push in the arrays as they are built in the two functions specified in the question.

**EDIT *per the latest information via comments***

Then when you want to reference the longest array and use it as a jQuery selector, you can use the following code:

```
var longest = arr[0].join(",") // arr was sorted to have the first index contain the longest array
$(longest).hide();
```

Comment: @frequent no, you could use `$('div:jqmData(role="panel"),div:jqmData(role="page")').each(function(index) {arr.push($(this).data("stack"))}` or what not.  My example is just a technical demo.

Comment: @frequent I apologize.  I should try to be more explicit in my answers.  I'll update for clarity.

Comment: ok. this works sort of. I can reset the array after I'm done.   I have more question: I can splice(-1) the last element of the array, but can I use it in Jquery syntax? If I receive **longest=["#menuPage"]** I hoped to be able to just call **$( longest )...**. Doesn't work though. Can you help out? THANKS already for the help so far

Comment: @frequent I would say do it this way:  `var longest = arr[0].join(",")`.  Then you can call `$(longest)`.

Comment: THANK YOU for saving my evening! That actually works... Also like this: var longest = arr[arr.length-1].join(",");

Answer (score 0):

```
var longestArrayStack = function() {
    var l = Array.prototype.sort.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
        return b.length - a.length;
    });
    return l[0];
});
```

Then:

```
var arr = [];
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').each(function(){
    arr.push( $(this).data("stack") );
});
var longestArr = longestArrayStack(arr);
```